# .htaccess mod_rewrite stop redirecting from sub domain to main domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Here is my current .htaccess file code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase   /xml-sitemaps/enternal-generator
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
RewriteRule   ^sitemap-(.*?)-(.*?)\.xml$      sitemap.php?type=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

When i open the url http://heartslovefree.com/xml-sitemaps/enternal-generator/sitemap.xml it working fine.

but when i open the site with my sub domain which is actually point to same directory http://zh-cn.heartslovefree.com/xml-sitemaps/enternal-generator/sitemap.xml it redirect me to main domain.

How can i stop redirecting? If i remove the .htaccess file redirecting stop but also my url rewriting for sitemap.xml to sitemap.php also gone.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude the subdomain from rule using a RewriteCondition ,try :

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase   /xml-sitemaps/enternal-generator
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub\.domain\.com$
    RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^sub\.domain\.com$
    RewriteRule   ^sitemap-(.*?)-(.*?)\.xml$      sitemap.php?type=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. I have write the code as 

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^zh-cn\.heartslovefree\.com$`

but still not working. For now i just hard coded one sub domain [zh-cn]. But we need to set the rule so that it work for all sub domains. We have 82 sub domains

Comment: Also @starkeen i don't want to exclude the sub domains from rewrite rule. The only problem is that currently sub domains are auto redirect to main domain.